# TypeScript: Passing parameters into a callback function

Tags: typescript, arguments, vscode-extensions

The following code are from the source code of the `azure-account` VSCode extension's code samples.

```js
export function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {
    const azureAccount = extensions.getExtension<AzureAccount>('ms-vscode.azure-account')!.exports;
    const subscriptions = context.subscriptions;
    subscriptions.push(commands.registerCommand('azure-account-sample.showSubscriptions', showSubscriptions(azureAccount)));
    subscriptions.push(commands.registerCommand('azure-account-sample.showAppServices', showAppServices(azureAccount)));
}
```

As you can see the code defines two commands, which means when the user use command `azure-account-sample.showSubscription`, it calls the function `showSubscriptions(azureAccount)`.

But how can the `azureAccount` object be passing through this way??? In my mind, the code should be written like this:

```
commands.registerCommand('azure-account-sample.showSubscriptions', showSubscriptions, azureAccount);

//commands.registerCommand
function registerCommand(callback, ...args){
    callback(args);
}
```

---

```
//defination of registerCommand from the source code of vscode api
export function registerCommand(command: string, callback: (...args: any[]) => any, thisArg?: any): Disposable;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`showSubscriptions` returns another function which is the actual callback

```
function showSubscriptions(account) {
    return function callback() {
        const sub = account.getSubscription()
    }
}
```